# Using Gradle with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

We are trying to setup a number of Gradle (v1.5) web projects in IntelliJ v12.1.2

The new JetGradle integration works fine until we get the the Artifacts

The module is imported as a Gradle project, the artifact is been created as a Web Application (Exploded) and the Web facet has been added - all the dependencies that are declared in the build.gradle file are correctly added to the WEB-INF/lib directory in the artifact

The problem comes when we make a change to the dependencies in the build.gradle file and refresh the module using the JetGradle refresh button - the dependencies of the module are updated correctly but nothing is changed in the artifact

If we changing just one dependency then the change can be done manually but if there are a number of changes or there are a lot of new/changed transative dependencies then it seems the only timely way to get the correct dependencies in the artifact is to delete and recreate it

Am I missing something obvious, does anyone know a better way to update the artifacts

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic artifact config update is not implemented yet. I've created corresponding ticket for that - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109369

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply - looks like you have marked this for v13. I will keep my fingers crossed it makes it.